# How do you reach this meta page from the main page?

Tags: support

I don't see any links to here from the main Money page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's at the top right corner of the screen. There's an icon looking like a chat bubble with a couple of horizontal lines, click on it and it will show up in the menu.